# Save multiple row of checkbox value into database

Tags: javascript, php, database, checkbox

I am creating a form that involves checkboxes. There is 5 checkboxes in a row. If the user adds another row, there will be another 5 checkboxes.

It looks like this, 
[image]

The code i used,

```html
<tbody id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Monday[0]" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday[0]" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Wednesday[0]" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Thursday[0]" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Friday[0]" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The code that i use for inserting the data to the database,

```html
<?php
                if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                } else {
                    if ($_POST['startTime']) {
                    foreach ($_POST["startTime"] as $key => $value) {

                            $endTime = $_POST["endTime"][$key];
                            $monday = isset($_POST["Monday"][$key]) ? 1 : 0;
                            $tuesday = isset($_POST["Tuesday"][$key]) ? 1 : 0;
                            $wednesday = isset($_POST["Wednesday"][$key]) ? 1 : 0;
                            $thursday = isset($_POST["Thursday"][$key]) ? 1 : 0;
                            $friday = isset($_POST["Friday"][$key]) ? 1 : 0;
                           

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO timetableschedule ( startTime, endTime, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) " .
                                    "VALUES ('$value', '$endTime', '$monday', '$tuesday', '$wednesday', '$thursday', '$friday')";
                            mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    }
                    }

                    echo "1 record added";
                    mysqli_close($con);
                }
                ?>
```

Suppose i submit the form the way i showed in the above image, i gotten this result in the database,
[image]

The value that suppose to be with the time "1600 1700" appeared on the "1400 1500" row. I would want the values to be saved accordingly as selected.

Comment: change the name of the checkboxes to `day[]`. This way the value `$_POST['day']` becomes an array with true and false info in it, where every row corresponds with the rows from the input. Replace day with actual day.

Comment: basically u are asking: form that has rows and add button, and submit button. At submitting the values from checkbox received. Am I right?

Comment: Other option, loop in Javascript over the rows and post as JSON.

Comment: @Mouser I'm not clear on how to use JSON

Comment: How are you getting your html code? And how new row is added on button click?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: removing the zeros (`name="Monday[]"`)  will not solve the problem because unchecked radio or checkbox elements are not submitted.

I would consider adding an index to your checkbox names while generating the rows, like:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="Monday[0]" value="1">

  <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday[0]" value="1">
```

...

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="Monday[1]" value="1">

  <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday[1]" value="1">
```

...

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="Monday[2]" value="1">

  <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday[2]" value="1">
```

This way your PHP loop should work

Comment: The same thing happened, the value did not go into the database correctly

Comment: That's probably caused by the way you loop it with the `foreach`.

Comment: @Mouser have been trying ways to loop it, but this is already the best i could

Answer (score 1):

The JSON way:

```js
function sendFunction()
{
  //tr
  var checkboxJSON = {};
  var i = 0;
  var tr = $("#dataTable > tr").each(function(){
      //checkboxes
      checkboxJSON[i] = {};
      $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
          
          if ($(this).is(':checked'))
          {
            checkboxJSON[i][$(this).attr("name")] = 1;
          }
          else
          {  
            checkboxJSON[i][$(this).attr("name")] = 0;
          }
      });
      i++;
  });
  
  var checkboxData = JSON.stringify(checkboxJSON); //send this to the server as checkboxdata!
  console.log(checkboxData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="dataTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Monday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Wednesday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Thursday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Friday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startTime[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endTime[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Monday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Wednesday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Thursday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Friday" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Send" onClick="sendFunction('dataTable')" />
```

---

For your solution. to work:

1. Set a hidden input to your form.

```html
 <input type="hidden" value="{}" name="checkboxes" />
```

2. Use an onSubmit event on your form

```html
 <form id="formDates" action="file.php" method="post" onSubmit="checkForm" />
```

3. Write the submit function with the checkbox code:

```js
 function checkForm(e)
 {
     e.preventDefault(); //prevents form from being sent to early

     var checkboxJSON = {};
     var i = 0;
     var tr = $("#dataTable > tr").each(function(){
         //checkboxes
         checkboxJSON[i] = {};
         $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){

            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
              checkboxJSON[i][$(this).attr("name")] = 1;
            }
            else
            {  
                checkboxJSON[i][$(this).attr("name")] = 0;
            }
         });
         i++;
      });

      $("input[type='hidden']").val(JSON.stringify(checkboxJSON)); //save this to the hidden input.
     document.getElementById("formDates").submit(); //submit all the data.
 }
```

4. In PHP you can rebuild this data into an array with `json_decode()`

```php
$checkboxes = json_decode($_POST['checkboxes'], true); //use true to set it as an array.
foreach ($_POST["startTime"] as $key => $value) {

        $endTime = $_POST["endTime"][$key];
        $monday = $checkboxes[$key]['Monday']; //key should refer to an INT. 0 for the first row.
        $tuesday = $checkboxes[$key]['Tuesday'];
        $wednesday = $checkboxes[$key]['Wednesday'];
        $thursday = $checkboxes[$key]['Thursday'];
        $friday = $checkboxes[$key]['Friday'];


        $sql = "INSERT INTO timetableschedule ( startTime, endTime, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) " .
                "VALUES ('$value', '$endTime', '$monday', '$tuesday', '$wednesday', '$thursday', '$friday')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Undefined index: checkboxes; Undefined index: startTime; Invalid argument supplied for foreach();

Comment: @Raymond, I've provided you with extra instructions, so you can try to implement this. My solution isn't tailor made, you have to implement and adapt it to your code.

Comment: Well nothing actually. The place where my checkbox code should be :D

Comment: Why is there a need to set a hidden input to the form?

Comment: Because that is where the checkbox data is stored into when sent to the server.